# Windows 10 suddenly CRAWINGLY and PAINFULLY slow with BSOD

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod, crash

I have combed all over the internet to get a solution for this problem and I can't get a solution that works. I use Microsoft Surface Laptop. My OS is windows 10 64 bit. Processor: Intel Core i7. 16 GB Memory and 500gb SSD. I specifically chose these specs because I usually do photoshop AND android studio. First year of purchase, this laptop was extremely fast as expected and I was totally in love with it. But after the second year, the slowness of this PC makes me hate it so much. This happens even when no programming is running. Even immediately after restarting. It is so slow to the extent clicking the start button takes about 10 seconds. Also, almost every morning, PC crashes with BSOD error message **"Driver Power State Failure"**

Here are the steps I've taken so far and none of them have worked (ie PC still slow and crashes):

1. I have updated my OS
2. I have adjusted the appearance and performance of windows
3. I have unistalled the display drivers, rolled back the drivers and updated the drivers. None of these options have worked. I'm currently using Intel Iris Graphics 640
4. I decided to disable sleep mode and activated hibernate yet the PC still crashes.
5. I decided to prevent PC from going to sleep and hibernation but noticed it started killing my battery. Also this only worked for a while until it started crashing again.
6. I have run the “sfc /scannow” command to fix the BSOD issue. Obviously hasn't helped
7. I have turned off most of the programs that run on startup to the barest minimum and I make sure to open very few tabs whiles using PC, yet PC still slow.

I want to avoid formatting my laptop because I have too many important programs and files and setting them up again could take me a month. I need help badly as I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: does the problem persist in safe mode?

Comment: 2 questions - How full is the drive? Have you properly investigated what is triggering the error on boot?

Comment: @Yorik PC is okay in safe mode but would crash either ways

Comment: @Tetsujin I have 10GB of space left.

Comment: do you have the "Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" driver installed? I believe it will be listed in the Device Manager.

Comment: @Tetsujin: can you clarify your comment? OP said 10GB and you refer to 50MB. Did you mean 50GB?

Comment: @Yorik - oops, yes. Minimum 10% free space at all times, more on a small drive. I think I should just copy/paste to a new comment with the correction, thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: [repost for bad typo] That is absolutely nowhere near enough. Your drive is choking. TRIM will not be working properly & your read/write will suffer very badly. With ineffective TRIM your actual write speeds will go from 600MB/s to more like 50 [far slower than an old spinning hard drive]. You need to clear at least 50GB space & keep it clear permanently, then you will have to wait for TRIM to catch up again. Leave your machine on overnight, don't allow it to sleep & eventually it will speed up again.

Comment: @Yorik no I don't have "Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" instlled. Do I need to install it?

Comment: @Tetsujin will this solve the BSOD issue too?

Comment: I doubt they are related; try it & see.